# JSF 2 enum property lost after bean validation

Tags: jsf, enums, bean-validation

Using JSF2 (MyFaces 2.1) and CDI (Weld) I use a selectOneMenu filled with an enum to conditionally render a second selectOneMenu (*doublemenu* in the code). There are several other fields in the form which are validated using bean validation.

The problem:

If there are validation errors after clicking on the commandButton and error messages are shown, the doublemenu will not reappear. It appears that *bean.type =='double'* is not true. But why? The selectOneMenu itself shows the option *double* as the selected item.

```
@javax.inject.Named
@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
public class Bean {

private enum MyEnum {
    Single, Double
}

private MyEnum type;

public MyEnum getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(MyEnum type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public MyEnum [] getTypes() {
    return MyEnum.values();
}


<h:form>
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.type}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.types}" />
  <f:ajax render="doublemenu" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup id="doublemenu">
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.type == 'double'}">
    <h:selectOneMenu ...>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:inputText id="VALIDATED"/>
<h:commandButtonaction="#{bean.save}"
</h:form>
```

BTW: *bean.save* is not executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your bean is request scoped. Request scoped beans are garbaged by end of every request and newly created on begin of every request. This also applies to individual ajax requests on the same view.

The `rendered` attribute is also evaluated during collecting submitted values (the *apply request values* phase). However, at the point the submitted values are to be collected, the `#{bean.type}` is obviously not been set yet (it has still to be set based on the collected submitted value during *update model values* phase). As your bean is request scoped, it would return the default value, not the submitted value from a previous request.

There are basically 2 ways to fix this.

1. Put the bean in a bit broader scope. JSF offers the `@ViewScoped` for exactly this purpose. This is in the current JSF 2.1 version only not compatible with CDI. If switching to JSF `@ManagedBean` is not an option, then you'd need [MyFaces CODI](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/cdi/) to bridge the JSF `@ViewScoped` transparently to CDI, or to wait for JSF 2.2 to get a CDI compatible `@ViewScoped` out the box.
2. Check a request parameter instead of a bean property.

   ```
   <h:selectOneMenu binding="#{type}" ...>
       ...
   </h:selectOneMenu>

   <h:panelGroup rendered="#{param[type.clientId] == 'Double'}">
   ```

Please note that this all is completely unrelated to enums. You'd have had exactly the same problem when using e.g. a `String`. Also please note that I fixed a typo in your code example, an enum value of `Double` is definitely not the same as `double`.

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)
- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183)

Comment: Thanks, the request parameter solution works for me. But I still wonder why texts in inputboxes stay in the form after validation but the enum value is set to default.